# Most efficient way to downsample a signal by a factor of 2.5x

Tags: downsampling

I know that to downsample by a factor of 2.5x one can upsample a signal by a factor of 2 and downsample by a factor of 5. I am wondering what is the best and more efficient way of downsampling by a factor of 2.5x?

Comment: You may have to benchmark your actual hardware to accurately determine efficiency.  If you require a FIR anti-alias filter for your desired result quality, you only need a 2 phase polyphase kernel with which you can avoid upsampling.

Comment: @hotpaw2 thanks for the response. The 2 phase polyphase that you referring to: how does it do the downsampling by a factor of 2.5? The downsample by a factor of 2 using two phase polyphase is straightforward, how about a factor of 2.5?

Comment: @TJ1: Without providing enough detail to make this an answer, think of a polyphase structure as a way of efficiently changing sample rate. As you noted, one way to solve your problem would be to interpolate by 2 and then downsample by 5. However, you're wasting work by first increasing your sample rate. Instead, a polyphase structure is cleverly structured so you just don't waste time calculating outputs that you won't use.

Comment: @JasonR thanks for the response. What details one would need to answer this question? Can you show how a downsample by 2.5 can be done with polyphase structure? A drawing or reference to an article would be great.